# Number of results of find-feature in sails.js restful api (in newer versions)

Tags: api, rest, numbers, sails.js

I started using the sails.js framework a few months ago because I need it's restful API.

In the first version a simple "http://domain.com:1337/mymodel" returned **all** datasets of the connected MySQL-database, however, after an update to V 0.10.xx it returns only the first 30 results.

I searched the sails.js changelog, documentation and various examples around the web and tried several ideas but I can't figure out how to force sails.js to return **all* results again.

Has anybody a solution for this?

Answer (score 14):

Use `sails.config.blueprints.defaultLimit` for general record limits.  This also serves as the default limit for populated associations.  There's technically no way at the moment to specify "no limit" for blueprints, but you can set the limit to the max number value as long as you don't have more than 9 quadrillion records :)

**config/blueprints.js**

```
defaultLimit: Number.MAX_VALUE // Set to highest possible value
```

Use `populate_limit` in your route config options to set the populate limit on a per-route basis.

**config/routes.js**

```
"GET /user": {blueprint: populate_limit: 10}
```

Use `populate_[alias]_limit` in your route config options to set the populate limit for a particular association on a per-route basis (e.g. `populate_pets_limit: 10`)

**config/routes.js**

```
"GET /user": {blueprint: 'find', limit: 20, populate_limit: 10, populate_pets_limit: 5}
```

I'll make sure this all gets added to the docs!

Comment: In Sails 0.10.5 defaultLimit: Number.MAX_VALUE does NOT work. Actually it coerces every find() to return just one row. I also searched the github sails docs for "Number.MAX_VALUE" and found no mention anywhere. Did you update the documentation?

Answer (score 7):

defaultLimit: -1 brings back all rows

Comment: I tested this answer with Sails.js 0.10.5 and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

if you need cange only populate limit, you can use populate_limit in sails.config.blueprints

```
// defaultLimit: 30
```

`populate_limit:999 //default value for populate limit`